# Is there a way to use validation on the textFilter of react-bootstrap-table2-filter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

Below is the object I use.

```
    {
        dataField: "hostname",
        text: "hostName",
        filter: textFilter({
            placeholder: t("hostName"),
            caseSensitive: true,
            delay: 3000,
            onFilter: (filterValue) => console.log("Filter value: ", filterValue)
        }),
    }
```

I want to achieve validation check before filtering. `onFilter` property seems to be working only after filtering is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Column%20Filter&selectedStory=Custom%20Filter&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) implementation of Custom Filter, I was able to implement a validation mechanism before calling `filter` method. Here is the code in case link breaks.

```
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import filterFactory, { textFilter, customFilter } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-filter';

class PriceFilter extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    column: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    onFilter: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.filter = this.filter.bind(this);
    this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);
  }
  getValue() {
    return this.input.value;
  }
  filter() {
    this.props.onFilter(this.getValue());
  }
  render() {
    return [
      <input
        key="input"
        ref={ node => this.input = node }
        type="text"
        placeholder="Input price"
      />,
      <button
        key="submit"
        className="btn btn-warning"
        onClick={ this.filter }
      >
        { `Filter ${this.props.column.text}` }
      </button>
    ];
  }
}

const columns = [{
  dataField: 'id',
  text: 'Product ID'
}, {
  dataField: 'name',
  text: 'Product Name',
  filter: textFilter()
}, {
  dataField: 'price',
  text: 'Product Price',
  filter: customFilter(),
  filterRenderer: (onFilter, column) =>
    <PriceFilter onFilter={ onFilter } column={ column } />
}];

<BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ products } columns={ columns } filter={ filterFactory() } />
```